# functors from partially applied function type

Tags: haskell, functor

there is a quesion in Programming in Haskell that says: 
Complete the following declaration:

```
instance Functor ((->) a) where
```

Now as Functor Thing has a type definition of:

```
instance Functor Thing where    
   --fmap::(a -> b) -> Thing a -> Thing b
```

I was wondering if this reduction makes sense:

```
instance Functor ((->) a) where
    -- fmap::(a -> b) -> ((->) a) a -> ((->) a) b 
    -- therefore
    -- fmap::(a -> b) -> a -> a -> (a -> b) 
    -- therefore
    -- fmap::b -> b
```

**-- update ---**
I missed brackets, it should have been

```
instance Functor ((->) a) where
    -- fmap::(a -> b) -> ((->) a) a -> ((->) a) b 
    -- therefore
    -- fmap::(a -> b) -> (a -> a) -> (a -> b) 
    -- therefore
    -- I should be returning a function of a -> b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because the `a` in your instance declaration is not the same `a` as the one in the type of `fmap`. You need to assign a type variable in your instance declaration that avoids ["capturing"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11332661/2225384) the `a` in the type of `fmap`:

```
instance Functor ((->) r) where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
```

Comment: thanks rein! To clarify my understanding:  the partial function returned from: fmap  (+1) (show) would take  3 and return "4"?

Comment: No, but `fmap show (+1)` would take `3` and return `"4"`. `fmap` here is `(.)`.